# ¿Como puedo obtener un valor de una fila pulsando un boton en dicha fila?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo esta función en javascript donde me dirije a un archivo PHP el cual me retorna un archivo `json` y lo muestro en una tabla de la siguiente manera.

Código JavaScript:

```
$.each(students, function(calificaciones, std) {
  $('#tableStudents').append('<tr>');
  $('#tableStudents').append('<td>'+std.matricula +'</td>');
  $('#tableStudents').append('<td>'+std.Alumno+'</td>');
  $('#tableStudents').append('<td>'+std.Grupo + '</td>');
  $('#tableStudents').append('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Calificar</button></td>'
);
```

Donde `$('#tableStudents)` es el **ID** que le di a mi `tbody` y lo que quiero hacer es que como cada fila va tener su propio botón, y que cuando se pulse el botón de cierta fila me traiga el campo **Matricula** de esa fila.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido @AngelAmayaE , sería genial que añadieras el código en formato texto para mejorar la comprensión y posible test.

Comment: pone tu codigo, no imagenes, para que los demas puedan editar tu codigo y asi ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 4):

En Primer lugar hay que aclarar que la forma en la que añades la fila es incorrecto, en realidad solo estás añadiendo en primer lugar el `tr`

```
$('#tableStudents').append('<tr>');
```

Lo que sucede aquí es que automáticamente JQuery crea el ta y su vez cierra el `tag` y luego añade `td` detrás de otro y no dentro del `tr` que es correcto.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto , puedes construir un `String` de todo y hacer un `append` directo a la tabla , o hacer el `append` al `tr` antes creado con `$('tr')` *(ejemplo)*

```
$('#tableStudents').append($('<tr>') //añadimos al tr
   .append('<td>'+std.matricula +'</td>')
   .... /* más filas */
); // cerramos el append a la tabla.
```

Además añadimos una clase que identifique la acción del botón dentro del `td` *( `.btncalificar`)*  para identificar mejor al momento de añadir el `Listener`

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btncalificar" >Calificar</button></td>
```

Haciendo uso de Event delegate añadimos el Listener ya que se añaden dinámica mente al `dom` , este listener debe estar asociado a un elemento que exista en el dom , en este caso la tabla con su id.

```
$('#tableStudents').on('click', '.btncalificar', function(event) { ...}
```

**Ejemplo**

```js
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#tableStudents').append($('<tr>')  
    // notese que no cerrramos el append , estamos
  // añadiendo al tr
    .append('<td> Matricula '+ i + '</td>')
  .append('<td> Grupo '+ i + '</td>')
  .append('<td> Materia '+ i + '</td>')
  .append('<td> Unidad '+ i + '</td>')
  .append('<td> Calificacion '+ i + '</td>')
  .append('<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btncalificar">Calificar</button></td>')
  .append('</tr>')
  );//cerramos el append a la tabla
  }
});

$('#tableStudents').on('click', '.btncalificar', function(event) {
 //Primera fila
 console.log("Primera Fila  : " + $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first-child').text());
 //todos las columnas de la fila  
  console.log("Columnas de la Fila");
 $.each($(this).parents('tr'), function(index, val) {
  console.log($(val).text());
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableStudents">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haria de la siguiente forma en cada boton tengo todos todos los datos, y cada vez que voy a presiona un boton me sale un modal con los input

introducir un ejemplo funcional

```
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
<!--
la idea principal es traer los datos de una fila, yo lo hago de la siguiente forma en la parte de html de boton le traigo un ejemplo 
-->
<html>
        <button class="massshow-modal btn btn-info" 
        data-id="34"
        data-nombre="marcos"
        data-apellido="alberto"

        ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>

        <button class="massshow-modal btn btn-info" 
        data-id="31"
        data-nombre="marcos_3"
        data-apellido="alberto_4"

        ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' class='form-control' id='id_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='nombre_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='apellido_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  // Show a post
        $(document).on('click', '.massshow-modal', function() {
            //$('.modal-descripcion').text('Vista de los Datos');
            //$('#msdelete').text(' ');
            $('#id_mass').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#nombre_mass').val($(this).data('nombre'));
            $('#apellido_mass').val($(this).data('apellido'));

            //$('#massModal').modal('show');
            //$('#acciones').attr('class', 'btn btn-info hibe');
            //$('#acciones').text('Visible');
            //$('#acciones').attr('disabled');

        });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```